# Issue with saving coordinates in onDrag function

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, sharedpreferences, coordinates

I am programming an app in which the user can buy buildings (imagebuttons) and move them freely using the drag and drop API. What I am trying to do is save the coordinates of the buildings so that they can be loaded back where they were left off. I am currently trying to use shared preferences but it does not seem to be working out too well when trying to use this in an onDrag function. Any idea what the best way to do this is?

Here is the code in the class that should be getting the coordinates to use (in runGraphics class):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Coordinates", MODE_PRIVATE);
colonyHutX = prefs.getInt("ColonyHutX", 0);
colonyHutY = prefs.getInt("ColonyHutY", 0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X: " + colonyHutX + " Y: " + colonyHutY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is the code that saves the coordinates (this is in the onDrag function in ColonyHutDrag class):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Coordinates", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putInt("ColonyHutX", x);
edit.putInt("ColonyHutY", y);
edit.commit();
```

The error I receive is the result of not having some sort of setContentView in the class, but since this is just a class that implements the onDrag function, it does not need the setContentView. If you have any idea what would be a better way of going about this or how to fix this issue as it is, please let me know.

Thanks guys.

Edit:

I tried to fix my issue by doing this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Coordinates", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Yet I still get the same error.

LogCat:

```
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287): Process: com.project.llb, PID: 29287
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at com.twentytwentythree.sab.ColonyHutDrag.onDrag(ColonyHutDrag.java:48)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:17635)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1300)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1286)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1286)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1286)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1286)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1286)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5338)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1100(ViewRootImpl.java:118)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3487)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
07-24 15:23:59.611: E/AndroidRuntime(29287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using an `Activity`, you need to call `getSharedPreferences` with some context.

Comment: Please look at the edit I added to the post. Thanks.

Comment: I added the logcat for you.

Comment: I see, `getApplicationContext()` is returning null. So, you need to pass context from some Activity. Pass the context(this) from an `Activity` to this class through constructor.